# Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example with Custom Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is a great example of a simple Google Map:
[Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

I am trying to add to this example the ability to assign each maker a custom Icon. 
Given the linked example:

```
var locations = [   
['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],   
['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],   
['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],   
['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],   
['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1] ];
```

I am thinking something like:

```
var locations = [   
['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4,'images/icon1.png'],   
['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5,'images/icon2.png' ],   
['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3,'images/icon3.png' ],   
['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2,'images/icon4.png' ],   
['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1,'images/icon5.png' ] ];
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/pra3K/) showing a custom marker created with the following codes.
You can customize the icon of your marker with the icon parameter when creating a marker.  For instance:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: latlng,
   map: map,
   icon: 'http://www.kjftw.com/gmap/images/icons/numeric/red10.png',
   zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
});
```

You can set the icon param with the location of your custom marker image.  Or in your case something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<locations.length; i++){
     myGlobalMarker.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map,
          icon: locations[i][4],
          title: locations[i][0]
     });
}
```

Where assuming `locations[i][1]` is the lat and `locations[i][2]` is the lng.  This is not tested, but it's a base for what you can do to create custom icon. `myGlobalMarker` is a global variable array that holds all markers.  I am not 100% sure if absolute URL or relative URL is needed for the icon location.  However, in my Google Map app i was able to use relative path to display custom icon on my marker.  This is the final result:
[image]