# google map api multi markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, icons, marker

i have to make a map for a company and i have to put the company logo on one marker, and a container icon on 10 others markers 
but i don' t know how to do it: 
this is my current code : ( so i have the first marker with my logo but its a personal image so can't see the marker ) 
do i have to make a new variable like "marker2" ? 
and make new variables for each position of the icons ?

```js
var nice = new google.maps.LatLng(43.7101728,7.2619532);
var centre = new google.maps.LatLng(43.7101728,7.2619532);
var marker;
var map;

function initialize() { 
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: nice,

                };

  

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    draggable:false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: centre,
 icon:'image/abi06B.png'
  });
  
  
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
}

function toggleBounce() {

  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas { 
       position: absolute;    
       height: 100%;
       width:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>


  <div id="map-canvas">
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example with Custom Markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666173/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example-with-custom-markers)

Comment: no i' m looking to make difference icons

Comment: The (new) possible duplicate has different icons for each marker.  You existing code doesn't include any information for the other markers.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question of 
`do i have to make a new variable like "marker2" ?`
it would be a yes and a no.

It seem like you might not be 100% sure about what these code does:

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    draggable:false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: centre,
    icon:'image/abi06B.png'
  });
```

the `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);` line, if for creating a google map in the 'map-canvas' element, and this function returns a reference to the map object, so that you can modify it later.

then, `marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map:map,.....` makes a marker with the settings you provided, which include title, or the icon image. This function also return a reference, which is a reference to the marker you just created, which is used for future modification you might need for your marker (changing the icon, or deleting)

so.. you need to do `new google.maps.Marker` a few (10) times, probably in a loop. But if you don't need the reference for modifying your markers later on, you don't need to make `marker2`, you can just use `marker`

Answer (score 0):

actually i find a solution, it' s look .... amateurism but it s work

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.7101728,7.2619532)
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);

  var image = 'image/abi06map.png';
  var image2 = 'image/garbage3.png';
  var Abi = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.7101728,7.2619532),
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });
  var Container1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Container2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Container3 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Container4 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Container5 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Container6 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Container7 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Container8 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Container9 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Container10 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image2
  });
  
  var Cannes = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.301728,7.2219532),
      map: map,
      icon: image1
  });
  
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```